# Parsing JSON in Retrofit android?

Tags: android, json, parsing, retrofit

I'm trying to parse the following JSON structure using Retrofit on android.

```
{
    "payload": [
        {
          "name": "Rice",
          "brands": [
            {
              "name": "Dawat",
              "subProducts": [
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "Basmati Long Grain",
                  "creditDays": 20,
                  "currency": "$",
                  "willDeliver": false,
                  "minPrice": 250,
                  "maxPrice": 400,
                  "sku": "1Kg",
                  "uom": ""
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "messages": []
    }
```

I have made models using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. The keys I'm particularly are payload-->name, brands-->name and subProducts-->name. Below is what I've tried so far. Can anyone please help? I can't parse this JSON Structure using retrofit

```
       productDetails.enqueue(new Callback<GetProductDetailsByPhoneNumber>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetProductDetailsByPhoneNumber> call, Response<GetProductDetailsByPhoneNumber> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response mil gaya", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            List<Payload> subProducts = new ArrayList<Payload>(response.body().payload);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetProductDetailsByPhoneNumber> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Interface:

```
@GET("wholesaler/getProductDetailsByPhoneNumber")
Call<GetProductDetailsByPhoneNumber> getProducts(@Query("phoneNumber") String number);
```

getDService()

```
public API getDService(){
    /**
     * The Retrofit class generates an implementation of the API interface.
     */
    if(service == null){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(API.class);
    }
    return service;
}
```

Payload.java

```
public class Payload {

public String name;
public List<Brand> brands;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Brand> getBrands() {
    return brands;
}

public void setBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
    this.brands = brands;
}
}
```

Comment: what is your problem? what you are failing to do?

Comment: I'm not able to call the endpoint and get response from it @WasiAhmad

Comment: can you provide the service interface and retrofit service generator ?

Comment: `productDetails.enqueue` should call the endpoint just fine. I assume `response.body()` works correctly to. Maybe you should log out any errors from within `onFailure`

Comment: Actually onResponse() never gets called

Comment: Try implementing `OkHttpClient`,and check detailed message from the server.

Comment: if it doesn't go to *onResponse()* , it couldn't get response from server for some reason

Comment: i recommend trying to send exact request with postman and see what is the response you are getting from server

Comment: I've been checking the endpoint using postman and its working fine. Not sure whats wrong here. @SepJaPro2.4

Comment: as @cricket_007 said, log/printStackTrace Throwable object in onFailure and see what's the problem.

Comment: @MayurBhangale, Can you please add the code sample of  "Payload" object..

Comment: @TejaDroid Added, please check

Comment: Can you please add code for GetProductDetailsByPhoneNumber in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, as you are not providing your "Payload"o bject

```
 productDetails.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

      if(response.body()!=null{
         JsonObject jsonObject=response.body();
         if(response.code() == 200){
            if(jsonObject.has("payload"){
              JsonArray dataArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray(HAS_DATA);
              if (dataArray.size() > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                 //your further code

              }
            }
         }
      }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

     //logic for if response fails

    }
});
```

Comment: The question has the payload object now

Comment: No. It's not my question. I don't need to try it. I'm saying you should update your answer because the Payload class is now part of the question

Comment: No, you should first try this, because Retrofit responses in Json format. And second you have again used a Brand class, which you have not provided again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your ***onResponse***:

```
if(response.code()==HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {   //HttpOk is the response code for 200
    if (response.body() != null) {
        if (response.body().payload!= null) {
            //data is there in an array of type payload
            //save all the data there
            //like you want the name, you can get that by response.body().payload.name and you will get "rice"
            //similarly if you want the name which is in subproducts array use : response.body().payload.get(0).brands.get(0).subProducts.get(0).name and you
            //  will get "Basmati Long Grain" 
        }
    }
}
```

The code will help you ***deserialise*** all the data from the JSON and you can store that wherever you want. Plus I will recommend you to keep a check on other response codes as well(such as 400 for bad request, 500 for internal server error etc). See here, you have your **payload** in an array, and there was only one element in it, that is why I have used `payload.get(0)`. In case of multiple elements in the array you need to use a loop and then fetch the values, same goes for your **brands** and **subProduct** array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an object PayLoad, and you have

```
{
"payload": [
    {
      "name"
```

this means it doesn't start with a parent, so you need to save the answer in a List like List and letter in the iteration you can use Response.get(position) <-- and this one going to be your payload number position, I hope this can help you